# Getting Assembly Errors With SignalR

Tags: signalr, nuget-package

I getting this error and I don't know what the issue is. The project  is using framework net48;net6.0 and we have NewtonSoft 13 installed.

[image]

Comment: Are you attempting to use .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET 6.0 (CORE)? If so, they are not compatible, you cannot mix the server/client technology.  Not sure if that is why you are getting the Newtownsoft.Json assembly error. But this may help you from going further down a bad path.